# How to integrate google docs with my java web application?

Tags: java, web, google-api, google-docs, google-workspace

I have application in which I have integrated ms office 365 , so user can open docx or xlsx pptx file from my web application to office 365 frame & Multiple users can co-auther it . Now I want similar integration of Google docs , sheets , powerpoint with my application . I have got idea about (g-suite) apis for sheets and powerpoint , But I am not getting any idea after searching it on internet. This link contains only apis for spreadsheet and powerpoint but not for docs. https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Same questions I have searched on google. I found a link
So have shared with you. Maybe it helps to you.
[Integrate Google Docs into web site for content creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028002/integrate-google-docs-into-web-site-for-content-creation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but I have shocked It's deprecated.